# Removing rows when a specific condition is met Python/Alteryx

Tags: python, alteryx

Right now I have a database that auto updates every month with new Adjusted values for the prior month. However, the previous values are still in the database but they do not show as 'Adj' in the column name. Once a new month comes in I would like to remove all values containing the unadjusted values of that month and all prior. I will try to explain below:

IF column Month contains 'Jan Adj' then exclude rows with month 'Jan'

IF column Month contains 'Feb Adj' then exclude rows with month 'Jan' and 'Feb'

IF column Month contains 'Mar Adj' then exclude rows with month 'Jan'' and 'Feb' and 'Mar'

IF column Month contains 'Apr Adj' then exclude rows with month 'Jan' and 'Feb' and 'Mar' and 'Apr'

IF column Month contains 'May Adj' then exclude rows with month 'Jan' and 'Feb' and 'Mar' and 'Apr' and 'May'

and so on for the remainder of the year.

Basically once we get the adjusted figures for a month, we need to exclude all rows for that month and the ones prior, I hope this makes more sense. Thanks

I tried to use a workflow in Alteryx that removed adj from column name then removed N-1 rows. However, there are multiple combinations of product types and regions sometimes there are no values for the prior month so it didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a [example]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.